# Sorting collection view items

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am developing an iOS app that shows items in a collection view.

I have included in the view a segmented control that should work to sort the items depending on different criteria.

This is how it looks like:

```
@IBAction func filtros(_ sender: Any) {

    let getIndex = sc.selectedSegmentIndex
    switch (getIndex) {
    case 0:
        print("barato")
        print(dispositivosTodos)
        var dispositivos_barato = [Dispositivos]()
        dispositivos_barato = dispositivosTodos.sorted(by: { $0.precio_dispositivo < $1.precio_dispositivo })
        print(dispositivos_barato)
        case 1:
        print("caro")


        case 2:
        print("reciente")
        case 3:
        print("cercano")
    default:
        print("no filtro")
    }
}
```

To test it, I have implemented the first case, that is sorting for a item value, in this case by item price.

Now, my question is how to update the collection view to show the items sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is create a new class-level var that will hold the sorted array. Then have your collectionView use ***that*** array for its data.

Add this in your class:

```
// original array
var dispositivosTodos: [Dispositivos] = [Dispositivos]()

// this will hold the sorted array
var dispositivosSorted: [Dispositivos] = [Dispositivos]()
```

and change your `cellForItemAt` to something like this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    // use Sorted array, not Todos array
    cell.myData = dispositivosSorted[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

and your `filters()` func will be changed to something like this:

```
@IBAction func filtros(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let sc = sender as? UISegmentedControl else { return }

    let getIndex = sc.selectedSegmentIndex
    switch (getIndex) {
    case 0:
        print("barato")
        dispositivosSorted = dispositivosTodos.sorted(by: { $0.precio_dispositivo < $1.precio_dispositivo })

    case 1:
        print("caro")
        dispositivosSorted = dispositivosTodos.sorted(by: { $0.propertyB_dispositivo < $1.propertyB_dispositivo })

    case 2:
        print("reciente")
        dispositivosSorted = dispositivosTodos.sorted(by: { $0.propertyC_dispositivo < $1.propertyC_dispositivo })

    case 3:
        print("cercano")
        dispositivosSorted = dispositivosTodos.sorted(by: { $0.propertyD_dispositivo < $1.propertyD_dispositivo })

    default:
        print("no filtro")
        dispositivosSorted = dispositivosTodos
    }

    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```